# Query using the results from another query

Tags: sql, join, oracle10g

I'm trying to write a query that will produce set of results based on the results from another query.  All the required data for the queries are from one table, just a different set of query criteria.  I'm not sure if what I'm asking is even possible to create in a single query.

```
select OBJID, case_type, activity, TITLE, x_rev_esc_prim_reason, x_rev_esc_sec_reason, x_esc_third_reason, x_create_dt, x_update_dt, x_sales_rep 
    from table_case
```

The results from the above query basically captures everything I need from the table, but I need to reduce the number or filter the results returned.

The results from the below query is what i need, to further reduce the results from the above query.  In addition, the query will also need the x_create_dt from the below query results to be greater than the x_create_dt from the results from the above query results.

```
select OBJID, case_type, activity, TITLE, x_rev_esc_prim_reason, x_rev_esc_sec_reason, x_esc_third_reason, x_create_dt, x_update_dt, x_sales_rep 
    from table_case
    where case_type = 'Sales'
    and activity = 'DO'
```

[IMAGE OF THE SAMPLE DATA AND RESULTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsWOd.jpg)

DB is currently Oracle10g

Comment: I think sample data and desired results would help explain what you want to do.  The obvious question is:  why not just use the second query?

Comment: the second query will only give me the results i need to filter out from the results from the first query.  i would like the first query to only return back results that are present in the results of the second query..  i need to check if there was a new 'OBJID' where case_type = 'Sales' that created by the same x_sales_rep, after a case_type = 'request' was created.

Comment: @Ron: You obviously missed Gordon's hint that you should show sample data and expected results to illustrate what you have in mind.

Comment: added image of the sample data and results.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to return all `case_type='request'` rows for each `sales_rep`, where the `x_create_date` is earlier than the latest `x_create_date` in a `case_type='Sales' and activity='DO'` row for that same `sales_rep`.

First we create the query that returns the qualifying information:

```
SELECT sales_rep, MAX(x_create_date) AS latest_date
FROM table_case
WHERE case_type = 'Sales' 
  AND activity = 'DO'
GROUP BY sales_rep
```

You can test this query by itself, and verify that it produces the desired results.

Then we embed this query in the outer query, and join the two, like this:

```
SELECT c.OBJID, c.case_type, c.activity, c.TITLE, 
    c.x_rev_esc_prim_reason, c.x_rev_esc_sec_reason, c.X_esc_third_reason, 
    c.x_create_dt, c.x_update_dt 
FROM table_case AS c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT sales_rep, MAX(x_create_date) AS latest_date
    FROM table_case
    WHERE case_type = 'Sales' 
      AND activity = 'DO'
    GROUP BY sales_rep) AS q
ON c.sales_rep = q.sales_rep and q.latest_date > c.x_create_date
WHERE c.case_type = 'request'
```

Comment: thanks!  i added an image of the sample data and the results.

Comment: OK, so clearly joining on OBJID is not what you want.  But looking at your results from Query 2, and your desired results, I can't discern how you are deciding which rows you want to include in the desired results.  Clearly it's not just based on the `x_create_date`.  Care to explain?

Comment: in my desired results, i only want to see records with a case_type = 'request' and where the x_create_dt is less than the x_create_dt, and from the same x_sales_rep from the records (from the 2nd query) with a case_type = 'sales'.  sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I caught the `case_type` condition in my edit, but not the `sales_rep`.  But what do you want to do when there are multiple records with `activity = 'DO'` for the same `sales_rep`?

Comment: In your sample results, it looks like you might be using the latest `x_create_date` of the records for that rep.  Is that what you need?

Comment: "I caught the case_type condition in my edit, but not the sales_rep. But what do you want to do when there are multiple records with activity = 'DO' for the same sales_rep?"  

- i would also like to capture additional records, as long the x_create_dt is greater than the x_create_dt from the request case type.   

there won't be more than two activity = 'DO' for the same x_sales_rep, 2 is the absolute max.

Comment: In your sample data, the two 'DO' rows for sales rep 1345 have create_dates of 12/15/2015 and 1/21/2016.  You have only 1 'request' row for that rep, and it has a date of 1/10/2016.  This is later than the value in the first 'DO' row, and less than the value in the second.  So I'm guessing that you want to use the latest of the create date values in the second query, for this sales rep.  Is that correct?

Comment: OK, give me a minute and I will update my answer to account for this.

Comment: Thank you Alan!  I really appreciate the help!